# how to publish php package so it will download `"name/mypackage": "dev-build"`

Tags: php, package, dependencies, composer-php

I have the access of a PHP Package called "name/mypackage",

and in my local computer system there is a file called composer.json that looks like this,

```json
{
    "require": {
        "name/mypackage": "dev-build"
    }
}
```

when i run `composer install`

it will show me this error `Problem 1 - Root composer.json requires name/mypackage dev-build, found name/mypackage[dev-main] but it does not match the constraint.`

So my question is what version should i use in publicly available `name/mypackage` package's composer.json file

```json
{
    "name": "name/mypackage",
    "version": "<WHAT_SHOULD_I_USE_HERE_SO_IT_WILL_DOWNLOADS_IN_MY_COMPUTER>",
    "description": "PHP Package",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "sachin"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thank You

Comment: I don't want to update composer.json file that is on my local computer system, please give me the answer without changing it.

Comment: Reading [this](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#version) note (the blue note) and the version name `dev-main` I *think* your package is currently published from the `main` branch of your repo so if you want it to be `dev-build` you probably should also create a `build` branch as well.

Comment: Thank You so much @apokryfos, i create another branch called `build` and when i update PHP Package, it saves into `dev-build`. Problem solved Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#version) on the composer.json schema

> Packagist uses VCS repositories, so the statement above is very much true for Packagist as well. Specifying the version yourself will most likely end up creating problems at some point due to human error.

This means that the version name `dev-main` is inferred from the branch name `main` and therefore if you want to use `dev-build` as the version name to use you need a branch called `build`.

It can also read tag names so if you tag a commit with say `1.0.0` then that will be used when requesting version `1.0.0` of your package.